# Same variable in select and where

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In the SQL, I need to filter out the date and construct the checking format. `correct_value` which will repeat many times in the query. Is it possible to avoid keep repeating the word?

```
select
    case
        value1 when 'correct_value1' then value
        else concat(value1 , '->', 'correct_value1')
    end as value1_check,
    case
        value2 when 'correct_value2' then value
        else concat(value2 , '->', 'correct_value2')
    end as value2_check
from 
    t
where
    value1 <> 'correct_value2'
    or value2 <> 'correct_value2'
```

Function can make it shorter, but still need to repeat it on both select & where. If that possible to simplify like

```
select
   check(value1, 'correct_value1') as value1_check,
   check(value2, 'correct_value2') as value2_check
from 
    t
where
    any not correct row
```

Comment: 1) Do you have to repeat it just three times? 2) Your first query does not require a case, the value will never be 'correct_value' as guaranteed by the where clause. 3) Do you have to make the query many times with different values? If so, put it in a [function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/postgresql-create-function/). 4) What does your table look like that you need to repeat a value so many times? That might indicate your table could be designed better.

Comment: Table is configuration data required to check on any wrong setting. And I want indicate the wrong value and correct in the result